# Combination of multiple bar charts and an overall line chart with aChartEngine (Android)

Tags: android, charts

I have the issue, that the bars are overlapping eachother and I have no clue how to separate them and the line chart should start from x=0 and cover the complete chart. I searched in several forum's, but I couldn't find the right solution...

My Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {<br/>
private static final int SERIES_NR = 4;<br/>
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = getDataset();<br/>
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = getRenderer();<br/>
private GraphicalView mChartView;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setRendererStyling();
    if (mChartView == null) {
        LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
        String[] types = new String[] { BarChart.TYPE,BarChart.TYPE,BarChart.TYPE, LineChart.TYPE };

        mChartView = ChartFactory.getCombinedXYChartView(this, mDataset,
                mRenderer, types);

        mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(100);
        chartContainer.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    } else
        mChartView.repaint();
}

private void setRendererStyling() {

    //Color
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
    //Size
    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(30);
    mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(30);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(25);
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(30);
    mRenderer.setLegendHeight(250);


    //General settings
    mRenderer.setChartTitle("This Week");
    mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0.5);
    mRenderer.setXAxisMax(10.5);
    mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    mRenderer.setYAxisMax(210);
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(1, "Mon");
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(2, "Tue");
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(3, "Wed");
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(4, "Thu");
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(5, "Fri");
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(6, "Sat");
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(7, "Sun");
    mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);
    mRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);
    mRenderer.setXTitle("X-Axis");
    mRenderer.setYTitle("Y-Axis");
    mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
    mRenderer.setGridColor(Color.GRAY);
    mRenderer.setXLabels(0);

}

private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getDataset() {

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    final int nr = 7;
    Random r = new Random();
    ArrayList<String> legendTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
    legendTitles.add("Bar1");
    legendTitles.add("Bar2");
    legendTitles.add("Bar3");
    legendTitles.add("Line1");
    for (int i = 0; i < SERIES_NR; i++) {
        CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(legendTitles.get(i));
        for (int k = 0; k < nr; k++) {
            series.add(100 + r.nextInt() % 100);
        }
        dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
    }
    return dataset;

}

private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getRenderer() {
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    renderer.setMargins(new int[]{30, 40, 15, 0});

    //Bar1
    SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
    r.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    //Bar2
    r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
    r.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ff8c00"));
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    //Bar3
    r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
    r.setColor(Color.parseColor("#696969"));
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    // Line1
    XYSeriesRenderer sollRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    sollRenderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    sollRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    sollRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    sollRenderer.setLineWidth(3);
    sollRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(sollRenderer);

    return renderer;
}
```

}